# Passing IEnumerable<model> and single model to same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have this view called Employee where I pass `IEnumerable<model>` to view to display a set of records in view as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Direct_Commercial_Van.Models.DCVViewModel.UserDetailViewModel>
@{
    var acc_status = "";
}
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="employeeTable">
      <thead>
           <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Full Name</th>
              <th>Account Status</th>
              <th>Created by</th>
              <th>Rights</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
              @foreach (var item in Model)
              {
                  if (item.account_status)
                  {
                       acc_status = "Active";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                       acc_status = "Inactive";
                  }
                  <tr class="odd gradeX" data-uname="User name_@item.username" data-accountlocked="Account locked_@item.account_lock" data-role="Role_@item.role" data-createdate="Created date_@item.created_date" data-uid="@item.e_Id" data-accessrights="Access rights_@item.access_rights" data-accountstatus="Account Status_@acc_status">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@item.first_name @item.last_name</td>
                        <td>@item.email</td>
                        <td>@item.created_by</td>
                        <td>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.last_login).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                        <td class="setpos"></td>
                   </tr>
               }
       </tbody>
</table>
```

Until this everything is good. Now I have a button in the same view which is **AddNew** and this will toggle a `modal` inside the same view which contains all `inputs` to accept details and the fields some of the attributes of the model. Below is what model contains:

```
public class UserDetailViewModel
{
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string last_login { get; set; }
        public string created_by { get; set; }
        public string created_date { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
        public bool account_lock { get; set; }
        public string access_rights { get; set; }
        public bool account_status { get; set; }
        public string e_Id { get; set; }
}
```

So what my problem here is, I want to strongly bind view `inputs` for adding new Record, with model attributes but since I am receiving it as `IEnumerable<model>` I just cannot use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.first_name)` etc., to strongly bind it. What is the best way to achieve this. How can we strongly use`IEnumerable` set of model to strongly bind a single record view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Create a partial view for `@model UserDetailViewModel` and use `@Html.Partial("_UserDetailView", new UserDetailViewModel())` (or `@{ Html.RenderPartial(..); }` to render the contents of the modal form

**Option 2**

Create a child action only  method that returns the partial for creating a new user

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public AtionResult NewUser()
{
  return PartialView(new UserDetailViewModel());
}
```

and in the view use `@Html.Action("NewUser")` (or `@{ Html.RenderAction(..); }` to render the contents of the modal form

**Option 3**

If you want to defer rendering the model form contents until required, use ajax to call a controller method that returns the partial for a new user and update the contents of the modal (this will require you to reparse the validator if your using client side validation).

**Option 4**

Create a view model containing properties for `IEnumerable<UserDetailViewModel>` and `UserDetailViewModel` however this will force you to use the `[Bind(Prefix = "..")]` on the POST method (or to pass back the main view model used in the view)

Side note: Your `UserDetailViewModel` contains a number of properties which appear inappropriate for creating a new user (such as `created_by` and `created_date`) which should only be set in the controllers POST method immediately before you save the associated data model, so a separate `CreateUserViewModel` containing only the properties you need will be a better approach, particularly for client and server side validation and protecting against over-posting attacks

Comment: Actually those values (created_date, last_login) I will not be using while creating the user and yea as you said I will be filling them in server end before inserting to dB but for editing the user they might be needed right.. So.. Anyways.. I'll try this approach once and I will get back to you buddy.. Thank you for the time.. :)

Comment: Which is why you should ideally have a view mode containing only properties you need, so that a malicious user cant post back values for those properties and potentially cause problems with your code. And for the Edit method, they should not be included in the view since they should not be editable (even as a hidden input). You should be posting your view model, then get the data model and map the properties of the view model to the data model and save the data model

Comment: So I need to have 2 different models for create and edit and wrap them into one model and then call that model in a single view? How about display details model.. Need to create separate model?

Comment: Not necessarily - but the key is that it should only contain properties your edit (and the ID property) and then in your POST method, map the values in the view model to an instance of you data model. In the case of a 'Create' method, just initialize a new instance of the data model, and in an 'Edit' method, get the data model from the database based on the ID. You model looks fairly simple so you could just use the data model for display (although personally I create view models for 'Details' so i can add display attributes)

Answer (score 3):

One easy way would be to use a wrapper model that conmprises your collection to display your records and at the same time the model for adding a new record. So like

```
class Wrapper
{
   public IEnumerable<CollectionModel> Records {get; set;}
   public AddNewModel AddNew { get; set;}
 }
```

Yet, this is not a good solution because your model then has two responsibilities.

What about a partial view that you implement where you have your model for add new and just render it into the display view? Then you could reuse this view for just its actual purpose, too!

Comment: Actually current view to display set of records and add new record will come under one partial view and if you are asking to separate this to 2 different concerns that that wouldn't be efficient.. But yea I liked the idea of wrapping them into collection and again as you said it won't be a good solution... +1 for the idea though and yea will take this approach if no one has any other way for this.. Thank you..

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a partial view that has `@model UserDetailViewModel` then in your main view you just call

```
@Hmtl.Partial("_UserDetailView", new UserDetailViewModel())
```

in your partial view you have your standard helpers..